# How to merge specific columns from many files in one file

Tags: bash, file, csv, awk, paste

I have 100+ tab separated files in one directory and i want to merge 2nd column from each file to one file.
I was trying to use `paste` like this:

```
paste -d" " *.tsv >> result.tsv
```

It appends everything, i can't figure out how to apply `awk '{print $2}'` to it. Can anyone suggest how to approach such a task?
Example input:

> file1

```
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
```

> file2

```
3 4 5 6
5 6 7 8
```

> file 3

```
7 6 5 6
2 3 4 4
```

Desired output file:

```
2 4 6
3 6 3
```

Comment: `paste file1 file2 file3 | awk '{ print $2 " " $6 " " $10 }'`

Comment: i need common solution with wild card, so i can apply to any number of files

Comment: do all files have 4 columns ?

Comment: all files have 9 columns, i simplified the example

Comment: `paste file1 file2 file3 | awk '{for(i=2i<=NF;i+=9) printf "%s ", $i; print ""}'` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gawk

```
awk '{a[FNR]=a[FNR]?a[FNR]" "$2:$2}END{for(i=1;i<=length(a);i++)print a[i]}' *
```

Comment: it says invalid option -v

Comment: WARNING: this won't always work properly, e.g. if the one of the files has fewer lines than a subsequent file, or if $2 is sometimes blank.  This approach also won't scale to handle more pathname specifications than will fit on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

If python is good for you, then you can use this script for any number of files:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

# invoke with column nr to extract as first parameter followed by
# filenames. The files should all have the same number of rows

import sys

col = int(sys.argv[1])
res = {}

for file_name in sys.argv[2:]:
    for line_nr, line in enumerate(open(file_name)):
        res.setdefault(line_nr, []).append(line.split('\t')[col-1])

for line_nr in sorted(res):
    print '\t'.join(res[line_nr])
```

Note: Script suggested by someone on Unix-StackExchange forum.

There is another solution too here [Link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158408/select-certain-column-of-of-each-file-paste-to-a-new-file)

Comment: python is good, but that script takes specific file names as second parameter and doesn't save the result to one file

Answer (score 1):

Trying for a solution without `awk`:

```
rm -f r.tsv
for i in *.tsv; do
    if [[ -f r.tsv ]]; then
        paste r.tsv <(cut -f 2 "$i") > tmp.txt
    else
        cut -f 2 "$i" > tmp.txt
    fi
    mv tmp.txt r.tsv
 done
```

It's longer than the `awk` solution, even when put on a single line.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple script that illustrates how a command-line utility capable of transposition (here [datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash)) can be used to paste together a specific column from each of a potentially large number of files.

```
#!/bin/bash
# requires datamash
TMP=$(mktemp /tmp/reshape.XXX)

for file
do
  cut -f 2 < "$file" |  tr '\n' '\t' >> $TMP
  echo >> $TMP
done

# -W means: Use whitespace (one or more spaces and/or tabs) 
# for field delimiters; the output will have tab-separated values
datamash --no-strict -W transpose < $TMP

/bin/rm $TMP
```